# How can I make a pause between two print functions

Tags: java, wait, sleep

I'm currently making the skeleton of a game inside of intelij because I can't do graphics processing yet. The current situation is that I need dialogue so there for I need to use print functions and pauses between them.

```
public class Intelijence {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("dfdfddd");
        ?
        System.out.println("dfdfddd");
    }
}
```

So I know some Ideas Like the sleep and wait functions but I'm not sure I am entering them in wrong or if they are just for another language
(BTW it's in java)

Answer (score 2):

You can use Java's [TimeUnit](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html) class. Specifically its [sleep](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html#sleep(long)) method.

For example, this would pause for 10 seconds:

```
TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(10);
```

And this would pause for 5 minutes:

```
TimeUnit.MINUTES.sleep(5);
```

Just add this line, adjusted for the time period you wish to pause, between your print statements.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Thread.sleep(milliseconds)` method to make calling thread go into a sleep state until the timeout (milliseconds) expires. It it also important to note that Thread.sleep method throws an `InterruptedException`, so your program will need to handle it accordingly -

You can do something like this -

```
public class Intelijence  {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("dfdfddd");
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        System.out.println("dfdfddd");
    }
}
```

This will make your `main` thread to sleep after 1st print statement and will print 2nd print statement after 5 seconds.

You can read more about this [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sleep.html).

Hope this helps!